# How to fix ' ReferenceError: matrixo is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

i require matrixo function that in random.js, but in server.js but program cant find this function. Where do i need require random .js for fixing?

server.js

```
 var matrix = matrixo(40, 40);

let random = require('./modules/random.js');
```

random.js

```
function matrixo(m) {
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        matrix.push([]);
        for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < m + 3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

module.exports = matrixo;
```

error - ReferenceError: matrixo is not defined

Comment: I guess "script.js" is actually "random.js".

Comment: You have to `require` `script.js

` in `server.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return value (which is the exported value) to the variable you are trying to use, and you need to do it before you use that variable.

```
let matrixo = require('./modules/random.js');
var matrix = matrixo(40, 40);
```